# How to replace the default text of the home page, when it is empty?

Tags: views, 9

On the Drupal 9 home page, there is a text displayed by default, when no content has been created.

I want to modify the text of this page, when there is no result. I go to the "frontpage" view and add an unfiltered text field in "Behavior when there are no results".

My problem is that it has no effect. I still have the default text that appears.

How to replace the default text of the home page, when it is empty ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on who is asking I assume this is Olivero theme and this is about the "Congratulations and welcome to the Drupal community" message, although you did not specify. If that is the case, you must override the template `core/themes/olivero/templates/views/views-view--frontpage.html.twig`.

Comment: Perfect thank you

Comment: The idea is that you accept correct answers.